# Are the downloads for OS X updates different depending on the language?

Tags: macos, software-update, internationalization

Are the downloads for OS X updates different depending on the language?

Specifically, I'd like to update two computers to Lion 10.7.3. The problem is that one computer is in English and the other in Japanese. Can I download the [OS X Lion Update 10.7.3](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1484?viewlocale=en_US) once from this page and install it on both computers?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the updates are not language-dependant. Certainly the documentation for the downloads support that:

> Supported Languages
>   Deutsch, English, Français, 日本語, Español, Italiano, Nederlands, Dansk, Norsk Bokmål, Polski, Português, Português Brasileiro, Pусский, Suomi, Svensk, 简体中文, 繁體中文, 한국어, Albanian, Arabic, British English, Bulgarian, Croatian, Czech, Estonian, Greek, Hebrew, Hungarian, Icelandic, Indonesian, Latvian, Lithuanian, Macedonia, Malay Malaysia, Montenegro, Romanian, Slovak, Slovenian, Thai, Turkish, Ukrainian, Vietnamese

(from the [10.7.3 combo](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1484) page).